# Laptop TouchPad not working in Ubuntu 16.04LTS!

Tags: touchpad

I am new to Ubuntu. I have recently started installed Ubuntu version 16.04.
But somehow the touchpad is not working. In the settings(Mouse and TOuchpad), the settings for mouse and touchpad is also not available. Here is the screenshot --> [image]

Below is the information that I received after typing the command `xinput` in the terminal -->  [image]

The output of the `dmesg | grep i2c` command is --> 
[    1.899616] i2c /dev entries driver

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: What is the kernel version `uname -a`. Please don't post screenshots. Copy text from a terminal.

Comment: Linux subham-Inspiron-5521 4.15.0-45-generic   #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 18:03:48 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dmesg | grep i2c` command.

Comment: And make sure that the touchpad is not disabled by Fn+ some button.

Comment: previously it was working fine in windows and it is not disabled by the Fn key

Comment: It's probably not supported by Linux. Try 18.10 live usb.

Comment: So you are saying that it can't be fixed?

Comment: It depends on what touchpad is installed. So try to boot from 18.10 LiveUSB 9you don't need to install) and see it the touchpad works there.